# Python 3.8.3. Функция "readline" читает не строку целиком, а некоторое количество символов с начала строки

Tags: python

Есть файл 'list.txt'. В нём несколько строк, вот таких:

```
abc
def
ghi
klm
```

Я хочу присвоить переменной значение, равное содержанию определённой строки. В коде ниже я хочу получить значение *второй* строки из файла 'list.txt'.

```
f = open('list.txt', 'r')
text = f.readline(2)
print(text)
```

Получаю следующее:

```
>>> text
'ab'
```

То есть, функция readline принимает в качестве аргумента не номер строки, а количество символов с начала первой строки. Я пробовал задавать число большее, чем символов в первой строке, но получал только полное значение первой строки. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не называйте переменные с большой буквы, так именуются классы и не нужно ставить `;` в питоне

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081836/6944845

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Описание метода [readline(size=-1)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html?highlight=readline#io.IOBase.readline):

> Read and **return one line** from the stream. **If size is specified, at most size bytes will be read.**
>
> ...

А чтобы получить определенную строку файла, как вариант, считать все и получить конкретную из списка строк:

```
f = open('list.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
print(lines[1])
```

Этот вариант подходит, для случаев, когда файл влезает в память

---

Если файл слишком большой, то можно считывать ища определенную строку, например:

```
num = 0
need_num = 2

while True:
    num += 1
    line = f.readline()

    # Если конец файла
    if not line:
        break

    if num == need_num:
        print(line)
        break
```